# vk_api: пересылка фото другому человеку через бота

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Я хочу при помощи бота, написанного на vk_api, в vk пересылать фото другому человеку. Например, я сфотографировал и хочу переслать это фото. Пробовал все: VkUpload метод photo_message, но там нужно указывать путь. Либо можно сделать так:

```
messages.send(user_id=id, message="_", random_id=0, attachment="photo27734343_8545241")
```

- я получаю attachment только что пришедшего фото, но метод его не отправляет (и нет никакой ошибки). Как быть, подскажите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Попробуйте поменять random_id, значение должно быть уникальным и меняться динамически при каждой отправке сообщения в диалог.
2. Если пересылаемый объект принадлежит не вам, нужно добавить access_key в формате: `<type><owner_id>_<media_id>_<access_key>`.